# Correcting for wildly incorrect time of .webm with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

I have a file that when I run ffpmeg -i on it will display a time of  351909:41:29.64.

I know I didn't record for 40 + years.  Any suggestions on what would be the best way to fix this?

I appreciate any and all answers!

Regards,

Comment: What is your ffmpeg version? Have you tried `ffmpeg -i old.webm -c:a copy -c:v copy new.webm` or the like?

Comment: To the OP, post the full output of `ffprobe` for the file.

Comment: ffprobe output

Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'recording.webm':
  Duration: 351909:41:29.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x360, PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio

Comment: ffmpeg version 0.8.13-4:0.8.13

Comment: That's an **ancient** version. Get something 2.8+ or nightly build.

Comment: Updating.  Thanks for all the help by the way!

Answer (score 8):

There is an old related bug report, marked as fixed. about this: [Incorrect duration displayed in webm file](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1444). This seems to be related to the fact that a webm file doesn't contain an index of all frames, but only keyframes.

First option is to rewrap the WebM

```
ffmpeg -i current.webm -c copy -fflags +genpts new.webm
```

Comment: I don't know if it's just an ffmpeg thing though.  I see it when watching the video in the browser and VLC.

I think it may actually be a file encoding issue.

Comment: As Metabolix said, rewrap it in a new WebM, except add `-fflags +genpts` to their command.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Kind of new to FFMPEG.  So the command would be ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i old.webm -c:a copy -c:v copy new.webm

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Updated ffmpeg, ran the above command and then used ffprobe and got: 

Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'new.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
  Duration: 351909:41:29.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x360, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio

Comment: I believe my file may be corrupt as I look at it.  The video seems to be only 6kb while the audio is 9000+ kb

Comment: Looks like it. How long is the file supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response.  It is actually supposed to be 16:54.